# Check if multiple dictionaries with the same keys have the same values

Tags: c#

Let's say I have an array of dictionaries. All of the dictionaries have the exact same keys. For each key, I want to return the indices of the dictionaries in the array if they have the same value for that key as at least 1 other dictionary.

For example, if there is a key "a" and `ArrayOfDictionaries[0]["a"]` and `ArrayOfDictionaries[2]["a"]` both evaluate to 7, I want to add to an empty `dictionary<string, int[]>` the pair ("a", [0, 2]).

I am very confused with the logic on how to go about accomplishing this.

Comment: What would happen if two dictionaries had a value of 7 for "a" and two different dictionaries had a value of 9 for "a"?

Comment: Hi @user3370908. What have you tried so far? Where is your code?

Comment: Instead of saying, *"Let's say I have an array of dictionaries. All of the dictionaries have the exact same keys"*, it's much more helpful if you post sample code that initializes the dictionary that you're referring to. Code describes sample data much better than written words.

Comment: A [mcve] would be awesome. What if the two dictionaries have different case sensitivity? Please also what the nature of the data is - in case this is a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly your logic may look something like this.
filteredDictionary will have the final result.

```
        var resultDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
        var filteredDictonary = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();

        var arrayOfDictionaries = new Dictionary<string, int>[]
        {
            new Dictionary<string, int> { { "a", 7 },{ "b",5},{ "c", 10 } },
            new Dictionary<string, int> { { "a", 8 },{ "b",6},{ "c", 10 } },
            new Dictionary<string, int> { { "a", 7 },{ "b",7},{ "c", 10 } },
        };


        for (var j = 0; j < arrayOfDictionaries.Length; j++)
        {
            foreach (var i in arrayOfDictionaries[j])
            {
                var uniqueKey = i.Key + i.Value.ToString();

                if (resultDictionary.ContainsKey(uniqueKey))
                {
                    resultDictionary[uniqueKey].Add(j);
                }
                else
                {
                    resultDictionary.Add(uniqueKey, new List<int> { j });
                }
            }
        }

        filteredDictonary = resultDictionary.Where(a => a.Value.Count() > 1).Select(a => a).ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key.Substring(0,1), kv => kv.Value.ToArray());
```

Answer (score -1):

If your array of dictionaries is named `src`, then for each key, you can group all the dictionaries with matching values and then convert to position lists. Converting the result to a `Dictionary` depends on how you want to handle the duplicate keys that result.

```
var ans2 = src[0].Keys.SelectMany(k => src.Select((d, i) => new { Key = k, Value = d[k], pos = i })
                                          .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Value)
                                          .Select(kvpg => new { Key = kvpg.First().Key, Matches = kvpg.Select(kvp => kvp.pos).ToList() })
                      );
```